# What other styles aside from hak fu mon and fu jow pai use claw styles as a core (or frequent) technique?

Tags: kung-fu

I've always had a cat mind, so I'm very attracted to the tiger style martial arts, but I don't have a teacher anywhere near me, as I'm living in the middle of Montana. So I'd like to know what other martial arts outside of kung fu have clawing techniques as a central or frequent point of the martial art.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, within Kung Fu styles, you may want to look into Eagle Claw Kung Fu or anything with a strong chin-na techniques as part of their curriculum.

In penjak silat, there is a variety of harimau (tiger) styles, with the Sumatran styles going quite low to the ground, and matjan styles of standing tiger.  Many of these use a small curved knife known as the karambit for attacking and controlling.

I've also seen a bit of East Indian fighting arts using palm claws primarily as a wrestling/disarming tool (as much as shredding the thumb muscles or fingers 'disarms' a person).

Comment: Of course, if you're looking for options closer to you, it's even less likely that you'll find these if you can't find any kung fu schools that even have a secondary tiger style as training.

Comment: Thank you! That gives me a good starting point! I wish I had a high enough reputation to upvote your answer.

Comment: No worries.  Hope you find something you can train in and have a good time with!

Comment: On that chat room you opened… You don't have to leave an answer, but lemme know if you saw my comments. Thanks.

Comment: Apparently SE has the worst chat room notification system ever, I guess? I answered again in your room.  Gah.

Comment: Sorry, i just saw these two responses. Uh ... what chat room? Would you mind reposting it here if it was to me?

Comment: Hi Bearcat, no worries.  Sandathrion and I have been trying to talk about a non-related topic for weeks and SE has not made it easy.  It's unrelated to your topic.